# Process Extract Jobs using .Net Framework Threading

Tags: asp.net, multithreading

I have a task to create a batch processing application that will run as a Windows service or an executable in windows task scheduler. The user will select a criterion on a Web Form that will be inserted into an Oracle Database table. The table columns consist of JOB_ID, PROCESSING_DATE, COMPLETED_DATE, FAILED_DATE. The watcher program will query the table for jobs on an interval (15 minutes). At any given time, there could be multiple jobs waiting to be processed in the table. I was planning on using treading, as I want to be able to update the table and set the PROCESSING_DATE, COMPLETED_DATE, FAILED_DATE columns when each event occurs. I am new to the threading concept and need assistance.

This is what I have so far:

```
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim lstJobCount As List(Of Integer)
        Dim objJobLibrary As New JobLibrary
        
        lstJobCount = GetEHIExportJobCount()

        objJobLibrary.run(lstJobCount)
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

 Private Function GetEHIExportJobCount() As List(Of Integer)
        Dim iJobID As Integer
        Dim lstJobs As New List(Of Integer)
        Dim oraDR As OracleDataReader = Nothing
        Dim oraCmd As OracleCommand = Nothing
        Dim sbSQL As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder("")
        Try
            Using oraConn As New OracleConnection(OraConnectionString)
                sbSQL.Append("SELECT")
                sbSQL.Append(" BJP.JOB_ID")
                sbSQL.Append(" FROM BATCH_JOB_PROCESSING BJP")
                sbSQL.Append(" WHERE BJP.PROCESSING_DATE IS NULL")
                oraCmd = New OracleCommand(sbSQL.ToString, oraConn)
                oraConn.Open()
                oraDR = oraCmd.ExecuteReader()

                Do While oraDR.HasRows
                    Do While oraDR.Read()
                        iJobID = oraDR.Item("JOB_ID")
                        If Not lstJobs.Contains(Jobid) Then lstJobs.Add(iJobID)
                        oraDR.NextResult()
                    Loop
                Loop

            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception

        Finally
            sbSQL = Nothing
            oraCmd.Dispose()
            oraDR.Close()
            oraDR.Dispose()
        End Try

        Return lstJobs

    End Function

Imports System.Collections.Concurrent

Public Class JobLibrary

    Public Sub run(ByVal threadCount As List(Of Integer))
        Dim workers(threadCount.Count - 1) As Task

        Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf JobProcessing)

        For i As Integer = 0 To threadCount.Count - 1
            Dim workerId As Integer = threadCount(i)
            Dim task As New Task(Sub() worker(workerId))
            workers(i) = task
            task.Start()
            inputQueue.Add(i)
        Next i
        
        inputQueue.CompleteAdding()
        Task.WaitAll(workers)
        outputQueue.CompleteAdding()
    
    End Sub

    Private Sub worker(ByVal workerId As Integer)
    
        For Each workItem In inputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()
                outputQueue.Add(workItem) 
        Next workItem
    End Sub

    Private Sub JobProcessing()
        
        For Each workItem In outputQueue.GetConsumingEnumerable()
        
        Next workItem

    End Sub

    Private inputQueue As New BlockingCollection(Of Integer)()
    Private outputQueue As New BlockingCollection(Of Integer)()

End Class
```

Any help would be appreciated.